# Excel VBA Can't Find a xlsx File in The Folder

Tags: vba, excel

Hi I have a code and it pops up a massage box with

> run time error 1004

that it can't find the file that I want to open. How can I handle it? I got stuck in it already for hours and I can't find what was going wrong. I want to open an XLSX file that is saved in the same folder with the macro file and they are the only files in the folder, can someone help?

```
Private Sub cmdStartMonth_Click()
'Optimize Macro Speed
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.EnableEvents = False
'Analyze month by selecting
Dim myPath As String
Dim FileName As String
Dim UnionWB As Workbook
Dim MonthName As String
MonthName = ListMonth.Value
myExtension = "*.xlsx*"

    Dim sWrkbkPath As String
    sWrkbkPath = Dir$(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\*.xlsx")

    'Only expecting a single file so no need to loop.
    If sWrkbkPath <> "" Then
        Set UnionWB = Workbooks.Open(sWrkbkPath)
    End If

UnionWB.Worksheets("Union").Range("A1:Y1").AutoFilter
With UnionWB.Worksheets("Union")
        .Activate
        .Range("L1:W1").Find(MonthName, , xlValues, xlWhole).Activate
End With

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

that is the problematic row in the code:

```
  Set UnionWB = Workbooks.Open(sWrkbkPath)
```

Comment: Are you able to open the file manually without errors?

Comment: [Dir](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/dk008ty4(v=vs.90).aspx) returns a *name*, not a *path*!

Comment: @ShrivallabhaRedij yes.

Comment: Why is current working directory such a hard concept?

Comment: @CommonSense Test the code. `Dir()` is bit misleading to me it seems. It is not faulty or incorrect code per se. I just tested code by running in different folders and it runs and picks workbook just fine. Maybe VBA  holds it in memory.

Comment: its working at my end. I think its issue with the file extension. @RafaelOsipov can you pls check the extension of the file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this

```
Set UnionWB = Workbooks.Open(sWrkbkPath)
```

to this

```
Set UnionWB = Workbooks.Open(Thisworkbook.Path & "\" & sWrkbkPath)
```